# Does updating a property need to happen on the main thread?

Tags: java, javafx

I've been getting an odd error at random times from this line of code:

`playHead.setValue(atTime)` (playHead is a `SimpleObjectProperty`)

`playHead` is used as part of a `Binding` which a `GUI` element (a `TableView`) relies on for its value. Does this mean that any time `playHead` is updated, it needs to be on the main thread?

As in, should it be:

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        playHead.setValue(atTime);                  
    }
});
```

This seems odd, as the class that contains the `playHead` should be able to function independently of the GUI. Is there any way to define the binding so that it executes on the main thread? That way, I can maintain good design practices.

Here is the callback for the `TableView` that returns the binding:

```
public class CuePreWaitCallback implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Cue,String>, ObservableValue<String>> {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(final CellDataFeatures<Cue, String> param) {
        final Timeline preWait = param.getValue().getCueTimeline().getPreWait();
        return new StringBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(param.getValue().getCueTimeline().getPreWait().playhead());
                super.bind(param.getValue().getCueTimeline().getPreWait().waitTime());
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Value Called---------------------------------------------->");
                    return preWait.getAbsoluteDuration().subtract(preWait.getPlayhead()).toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(0);
                    return "";
                }

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything that touches the GUI (e.g. the scenegraph) must be executed on the application thread, so your assumption about using runLater is correct if you are updating from a background thread.

What you could do to make your domain logic independent of your UI logic is to have a sort of "proxy" property in your UI related code that is not bound to anything in the UI; that than would be safe to bind from a background thread. Then set a listener on the proxy, within that listener use runLater to update the actual UI property.

So the general answer to the question in the title is "no", only "yes" if that property is somehow connected to the scenegraph.